# Any research on label/target variable design for ML training?

Tags: machine-learning, prediction

is there any discussion or paper about how to define/design the labels for the ML training? Intuitively I can think of:

- Net return of the next future day
- Net return using the max candle-high value of the next N candles
- There is also a process described in the book "advances in financial machine learning" ([https://www.amazon.com/Advances-Financial-Machine-Learning-Marcos/dp/1119482089](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/1119482089)) but the book lacks somehow on justification and evaluation.

So in general: how to define your target variables (labels if classification) for stock predictions?

Thank you!

Comment: It almost seems a machine learning problem upon a machine learning problem: what is the best labelling or discrete labelling distribution to return the best test results from my original machine learning algorithm...

Answer (score 1):

A good beggining could be the paper of [Gu, Kelly and Xiu (2018)](http://dachxiu.chicagobooth.edu/download/ML.pdf).

Comment: The paper greatly illustrates the features, but for labelling it simply uses the net return of the next time stamp.

Answer (score 0):

I see there that you mentioned the text book Advances in Financial Machine Learning. At the back of every chapter are a list of good papers that provide some insight into the chapters body of knowledge. Chapter 3 is titled Labeling and it is of course a large part of the process.

I suggest reading all 39 papers in the bibliography. It was a real eye opener and they are well selected so you build a very deep understanding of the various techniques.

Comment: thank you! Will definitely take a look into this

Comment: Yeah, the papers show super basic stuff tipping in the dark. Simply applying svm, trees or similar old concepts on net returns between samples.  My next steps will be to define the labels as a result of a entry/exit strategy such as from here: https://www.quora.com/What-are-day-trading-entry-and-exit-points